How can I get the template id/name or text sent through whatsapp cloud API?
I need a way to get or track the WhatsApp template sent to customers. I'm currently using an external sender to automate the whatsapp template sending and in my webhook I'm getting this notification:
    {'object': 'whatsapp_business_account',
     'entry': [{'id': 'ID',
       'changes': [{'value': {'messaging_product': 'whatsapp',
          'metadata': {'display_phone_number': 'DISPLAY_PHONE_NUMBER',
           'phone_number_id': 'PHONE_NUMBER_ID'},
          'statuses': [{'id': 'wamid.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'status': 'sent',
            'timestamp': '1712986555',
            'recipient_id': 'RECIPIENT_ID',
            'conversation': {'id': '9A7854c10f69ed20ec87620XW106A63b4',
             'expiration_timestamp': '1712942700',
             'origin': {'type': 'marketing'}},
            'pricing': {'billable': True,
             'pricing_model': 'CBP',
             'category': 'marketing'}}]},
         'field': 'messages'}]}]}

How can I get to know at least the template ID from this? Ideally the template text, but knowing the template ID can get me to template text.
